# Container apps connecting to SQL database using user-assigned managed identity: Failed to acquire token from MSI Endpoint (MSI Token failure)

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-sql-database, azure-managed-identity, azure-container-apps

I'm receiving the error below when deploy a container apps connecting to SQL database using user-assigned managed identity.

```
ERROR 1 --- [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool: HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: MSI Token failure: Failed to acquire token from MSI Endpoint
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerSecurityUtility.getMSIAuthToken(SQLServerSecurityUtility.java:499) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2.3.jre17.jar:na]
...
```

Here are the important parts of my Spring Boot application:

*pom.xml*

```xml
...
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
...
```

*application.properties*

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://danieltestsqlserver1101.database.windows.net:1433;databaseName=testdatabase01;msiClientId=<managed-identity-client-id>;authentication=ActiveDirectoryMSI;
```

And here is my Azure setup:

1. User-assigned managed identity "mi-test-app" created.
2. AD group "DB admin" created with "mi-test-app" and my main user as owners and members.
3. SQL server created and "DB admin" group set as administrator.
4. Private endpoint created for SQL server (public access was disabled).
5. Private DNS zone created and proper virtual network link added.
6. SQL database created and configured with:

```sql
CREATE USER [mi-test-app] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [mi-test-app];
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [mi-test-app];
ALTER ROLE db_ddladmin ADD MEMBER [mi-test-app];
GO
```

7. Container apps created with new own environment.
8. Managed identity "mi-test-app" added as identity in container apps.
9. Container apps revision restarted.

When started, the process fail with the error above.

I tried to set SQL server with public access and allowing Azure services and resources to access it but doesn't work.

Any help would be welcome.

[image]

Comment: if you connect to the console can you reach the MSI endpoint form within the container app ?

Comment: it's unstable, using `az containerapp exec -n aca-main -g rg-test --command bash` connected and suddenly `ERROR: {"Error":{"Code":"ClusterExecEndpointWebSocketConnectionError","Message":"Failed to establish WebSocket connection with the container, error is Failed to establish WebSocket connection with Managed Environment exec endpoint, error: The server returned status code \u0027500\u0027 when status code \u0027101\u0027 was expected..","Details":null,"Target":null,"AdditionalInfo":null}} Disconnecting...`

Comment: UPDATE: upgrading version of mssql-jdbc from 11.2.3.jre17 to 12.3.0.jre17-preview and azure-identity from 1.5.4 to 1.9.0 result in `com.azure.identity.CredentialUnavailableException: Managed Identity authentication is not available.`

Comment: @dgolive I am struggling with the same. Did you figure it out?